# Is there any verse or historical evidence suggesting that manusmriti is more authoritative than other smritis?

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, pramana

1) Among Dharmasmritis(Manusmriti, Naradasmriti , Parashara Smriti,Yajnavalkya Smrti ... etc) , **is there any verse or historical evidence which suggests that manusmriti is more authoritative/followed than others(Narada smriti, Parashar Smriti,..)** or whether all have equal authority? What if two dharma shastras verses clash with each other, which one will prevail.

2) Dharma shastras which are of later date, is there any evidence that Dharma shastras's law has to be more authoritative than older 'Dharmasutra' (like Gautama dharmasutras)?

Comment: no. in fact the manu smriti has never been followed universally across India...other smritis have been followed in different locations.

Comment: In Bengal Hindus have not followed Manu Smriti for centuries and instead were following Raghunandan Smriti.

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26096/in-which-sect-of-hinduism-manusmriti-is-canonical-text/26097#26097 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26646/is-it-permissible-to-deny-the-authority-of-manusmriti/26670#26670 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27381/if-there-is-difference-of-opinion-between-purana-and-gita-and-dharmashashtrasli

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer, please accept it.

Comment: @Ikshvaku: you said "Also in the Veda:

    We have the Veda itself testifying to the trustworthy character of at least one Smṛti-writer, Manu—‘Whatever Manu has said is wholesome."

Please give reference of shloka number of veda, and I will instantly accept your answer, because that is a very important quote, which you have made

Comment: @zaxebo1 Already I added it to my answer. Please check.

Comment: What is Raghunandan Smriti? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: In Bengal Pandit Raghunandan modified Manu Smiriti a few hundred years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) Among Dharmasmritis(Manusmriti, Naradasmriti , Parashara
>   Smriti,Yajnavalkya Smrti ... etc) , is there any verse or historical
>   evidence which suggests that manusmriti is more authoritative/followed
>   than others(Naradsmriti,Parashar Smriti,..) or whether all have equal
>   authority? What if two dharmasmritis verses clash with each other,
>   which one will prevail.

Medhātithi is [his commentary](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145579.html) on the Manusmriti says this:

> Among Smṛtis Manu is most authoritative, as says Aṅgiras—.... as also the Veda.
>
> Any Smṛti that goes against the ordinances of Manu is to be rejected—as declared by Bṛhaspati (see above). This is the view of the Kalpataru also

Also in the Veda:

> We have the Veda [itself testifying](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31999/11726) to the trustworthy character of at least one Smṛti-writer, Manu—‘Whatever Manu has said is wholesome.’

And the Parāśara Smriti:

> Parāśara-Smṛti, 1.21.—‘During each Kalpa Manu declares the Dharmas.’

However, most texts state that all the Smriti texts including all the Dharma Shastras have equal authority, and the Manusmriti itself declares this:

> The entire Veda is the root-source of Dharma; **also the Conscientious
>   Recollection of righteous persons versed in the Veda**, the Practice of
>   Good (and learned) Men, and their self-satisfaction.—(6)
>
> The Veda should be known as the ‘revealed word,’ **and the Dharmaśāstra
>   as the ‘recollections’**; in all matters, these two do not deserve to be
>   criticised, as it is out of these that Dharma shone forth.—(10)
>
> The Veda, **the Smṛti**, the Practice of cultured Men, and what is
>   agreeable to oneself—these directly constitute the fourfold means of
>   knowing Dharma.—(12)

Whenever there is a conflict between two Vedic texts, there is an option to follow either injunction.

Whenever there is conflict between Smriti and Vedas, Vedas take priority because they are more authoritative and because the Smriti texts are based on the Vedas.

Whenever there is a conflict between two Smriti texts, **there is an option to follow either injunction**, just like in the case of conflicting Vedic texts.

The Manusmriti itself says this:

> Where there is conflict between two Vedic texts, both are held to be Dharma; both have been rightly pronounced by the wise to be Dharma.—(14)

Next,

> 2) 'DharmaSmritis' which are of later date, is there any evidence that Dharmasmritit's law has to be more authoritative than older 'Dharmasutra' (like Gautam dharmasutras)?

There is no Smriti or Shruti text that says that an older text is more authoritative than a newer one (and vice versa). The reasoning is because as long as Smriti agrees with Shruti, which is eternal, then it is authoritative.

Comment: Taittriya Samhita 2.2.6.2 verse quoted by you is wrong.

Comment: @NaveenKick What do you mean it's wrong? Like verse 2.2.6.2 is a different verse from the one quoted, or the verse itself is factually incorrect?

Comment: Verse 2.2.6.2 is a different verse from the one you quoted. I think you copied from wisdomlib.org

Comment: @NaveenKick Oh, yes you're right. I got it from the commentary for that verse on wisdomlib.org.

Comment: Okay. Wrong citation is mentioned in the commentary. As far as I know, Nothing says Manusmriti is more authoritative. In my opinion, it is only the five Dharmasastras (Vishnu, Vasista, Apastamba,  Baudhayana, and Gautama) are most authoritative as they form part of Kalpa Sutra, which is a Vedanga.

Comment: @NaveenKick Check this question I just posted: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/which-dharma-sutras-are-valid-according-to-sri-vaishnavas