# if there is difference of opinion between purana and gita and dharmashashtras(like: manusmriti etc), which will take more precedence?

Tags: scripture, puranas, smriti, manu-smriti, pramana

if there is difference of opinion between purana and bhagvad gita and dharmashashtras(like: manusmriti etc), and they are interpreting vedas in their own manner to support their views.

**Now, then which one (gita,purana, dharmashashtras)  will take more precedence?**

among gita - bhagvad gita, uddhav gita,shiva gita,ishvara gita, guru gita which one is more authoritative ?

---

(note: it will be appreciated, if you quote references for your answer)

Comment: You may want to specify which references are acceptable given this is a question on precedence of references in the literal sense.

Comment: References are mandatory. Not appreciated. That sentence is not needed.

Comment: Among Smritis and Puranas, Smritis have more authority.. Gita is a part of an Itihasa.. I think Itihasa and Purana have equal authority.. but not so sure on this.. I have already a Q/A on this which also answers ur Q at least partially: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16509/which-shastras-are-more-authoritative-the-smritisdharma-shastras-or-the-purana

Comment: Related: [Is the heirarchy of scriptures discussed in any scripture or in the works of Acharyas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20664/277)

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26096/in-which-sect-of-hinduism-manusmriti-is-canonical-text/26097#26097 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26646/is-it-permissible-to-deny-the-authority-of-manusmriti/26670#26670

Answer (score 1):

**They are not comparable due to different nature**.
I fear, you are comparing apples vs oranges vs mangoes.

> The [Puranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas), are ancient Hindu texts eulogizing various deities, primarily the divine Trimurti God in Hinduism through **divine stories**.
>
> [Smriti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smriti), literally "**that which is remembered**" are a body of Hindu texts usually attributed to an author, traditionally written down but constantly revised, ... Smriti is a derivative secondary work and is considered **less authoritative than Sruti** in Hinduism
>
> [Shruti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Aruti) in Sanskrit means "**that which is heard**" and refers to the body of most authoritative, ancient religious texts comprising the central canon of Hinduism. It includes the **four Vedas** ...

[Bhagavad] Gita falls either under Smriti or Sruti according to Wikipedia references and also discussed here:
[Is Bhagavad Gita text Shruti or Smriti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8959/1049)

---

- Puranas are "stories", which might be historical or imaginary, for the purpose of lesson learning & revering certain God.
- They can't be compared with Dharma ShAstra-s, which are definitive guidelines, how to live the social life, in real time.
- Similarly both of them can't be compared with Gita, which was said in a **private conversation**, & not for general availability. It's Not about "how to live life", rather it's about, "how not to get another life again"!
  Also see: [What is the core message of the Bhagavad-gītā? What are some verses from Bhagavad-gītā that one can refer to, to enrich life in general?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16185/1049)
  <sup>The second part of Qn title is ironically asking about enriching "life" :-)</sup>

---

Regarding comparisons among various Gita, the same notion as above applies. Different Gita-s could have been said in different context. Hence should not be compared.

Comment: regarding "varna vyavastha" - these texts have conflicting opinions

Comment: @zaxebo1, it's better to ask a separate Qn in such case. As discussed in answer, generally: `PurAna < Smruti < Shruti`.

Comment: regarding shruti highest, can you answer this question of mine , 'agamas is included in shruti or not' https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27389/how-can-agama-be-treated-as-shruti

Comment: @zaxebo1 no contradiction