# Which Dharma Sutras are valid according to Sri Vaishnavas?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, dharma-shastras

Which Dharma Sutras are valid? Is every Dharma Sutra named after a historic Rishi with the affix "Sutra" or "Shastra" or "Smriti" valid?

On wisdomlib.org for [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145579.html) Manusmriti verse, [Ganganath Jha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganganath_Jha) talks about the lists of valid Dharma Sutras composed by different authors.

Interestingly, the Manusmriti is unanimously cited as the foremost authority on Dharma.

> We have the Veda itself testifying to the trustworthy character of at
>   least one Smṛti-writer, **Manu**—‘Whatever **Manu** has said is wholesome.’
>
> Madanapārijāta, p. 11.— "**Manu** is the most important of the expounders
>   of law..."
>
> Nṛsiṃhaprasāda-Saṃskāra MSS. - ".....and as **Manu and others** are
>   known to have been learned in the Veda it stands to reason that
>   knowing as they did that the Veda was the sole authority on Dharma...
>
> Smrticandrikā, pp. 1 et scq.— "The ordinances composed by **Manu** and
>   other writers..."
>
> Among Smṛtis **Manu** is most authoritative, as says Aṅgiras—.... as
>   also the Veda.
>
> Any Smṛti that goes against the ordinances of **Manu** is to be
>   rejected—as declared by Bṛhaspati (see above). This is the view of the
>   Kalpataru also

But anyways, here is a list compiled by Yajnavalkya of valid Dharma Sutras. Note that Manu is on top:

> Manu, Viṣṇu, Yama, Aṅgiras, Vaśiṣṭha, Dakṣa, Saṃvarta, Śātātapa,
>   Parāśara, Āpastamba, Uśanas, Vyāsa, Kātyāyana, Bṛhaspati, Gautama,
>   Śaṅkha-Likhita, Hārīta, Atri, and Yājñavalkya himself.

According to Vyasa:

> Manu, Vaśiṣṭha, Kaśyapa, Garga, Gautama, Uśanas, Atri, Viṣṇu,
>   Saṃvarta, Dakṣa, Aṅgiras, Śātātapa, Hārīta, Yājñavalkya, Āpastamba,
>   Śaṅkha, Likhita, Kātyāyana, Pracetas.

So aside from the Manusmriti, which Dharma Shastras, and their particular manuscripts, are valid according to Sri Vaishnava acharyas?