# Where is this verse from in the Vedas about the Manusmriti?

Tags: vedas, identification-request, manu-smriti, pramana

This verse is [said](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145579.html) to exist in the Vedas:

> *yad vai manuravadat tad bheṣajam*
>
> ‘Whatever Manu has said is medicine.’

Comment: Current Manusmriti is definitely not written by Manu. Everyone knows that Manu is referred to in third person. – And as per current Manusmriti caste law many authors of sacred scriptures are totally debarred from sacred thread and ceremonies. We also know that Manu's children, grandchildren etc. repeatedly changed varna so definitely Manusmriti is not Manu's work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### [Krishna Yajurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda#Krishna_Yajurveda) ➡ Taittariya Samhita : 2.2.10.2

Quoting Sanskrit text from [Wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE(%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D_%E0%A5%A8/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8): Taittariya Samhita, Adhyaya-2, Prapathaka-2, Anuvaka-10, 2<sup>nd</sup> Mantra:

> VERSE: 2
>
> वै तिष्यः सोमः पूर्णमासः साक्षाद् एव ब्रह्मवर्चसम् अव रुन्द्धे
> परिश्रिते याजयति ब्रह्मवर्चसस्य परिगृहीत्यै
> श्वेतायै श्वेतवत्सायै दुग्धम् मथितम् आज्यम् अभवत्य् आज्यम् प्रोक्षणम् आज्येन मार्जयन्ते यावद् एव ब्रह्मवर्चसं तत् सर्वं करोत्य् अति ब्रह्मवर्चसं क्रियत इत्य् आहुः ।
> ईश्वरो दुश्चर्मा भवितोर् इति मानवी ऋचौ धाय्ये कुर्याद् **यद् वै किं च मनुर् अवदत् तद् भेषजम् ।**

You can refer [Krishna Yajurveda Taittariya Samhita](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/yajur_veda/taittiriya_krishna_yajur_veda.pdf) in authentic/original format from Vedic Reserve, 2.2.10: (see pg. 105):

> [image]

Transliteration from [Sanskritweb.net](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/ts-find.pdf):

> [[2-2-10-2]]
> vai tişyaḥ somaḥ pūrņamāsaḥ sākṣād eva brahmavarcasam ava runddhe parisrite yājayati brahmavarcasasya parigrhītyai śvetāyai śvetavatsāyai dugdham mathitam ājyam abhavaty ājyam proksanam ājyena mārjayante yavad eva brahmavarcasam tat sarvam karoty ati brahmavarcasam kriyata ity āhus | iśvaro duścarmā bhavitor iti mānavi scau dhāyye kuryād **yad vai kim ca manur avadat tad bhesajam** ||

The English translation from [Sanskritweb.net](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/keith.pdf):

> [[2-2-10]]
> Yonder sun did not shine, the gods sought an atonement for him, for him they offered this oblation
> to Soma and Rudra: verily thereby they bestowed brightness upon him. If he desires to become
> resplendent, he should offer for him this oblation to Soma and Rudra; verily he has recourse to
> Soma and Rudra with their own portion; verily they bestow upon him splendour; he becomes
> resplendent. He should offer on the full moon day of the month Tisya; Tisya is Rudra [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuNtW.png), the full
> moon is Soma; verily straightway he wins splendour. He makes him sacrifice on an enclosed (altar),
> to acquire splendour. The butter is churned from milk of a white (cow) with a white calf; butter is
> used for the sprinkling, and they purify themselves with butter; verily he produces whatever
> splendour exists. 'Too much splendour is produced', they say, 'he is liable to become a leper'; he
> should insert the verses of Manu's; **whatever Manu said is medicine [2]**

Comment: what does it actually mean? is there any prescription of Manu about these?

Comment: and does 'whatever Manu said' mean the Manusmriti?

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Yes, "whatever Manu has said," means the Manusmriti, according to Medhatithi, a medieval Manusmriti commentator.

Comment: Who is "they?" Quotation marks don't exist in the Veda's Sanskrit so "whatever Manu said is medicine" could be in quotes

Comment: Current Manusmriti is definitely not written by Manu. Everyone knows that Manu is referred to in third person.

Comment: And as per current Manusmriti caste law many authors of sacred scriptures are totally debarred from sacred thread and ceremonies. We also know that Manu's children, grandchildren etc. repeatedly changed varna so definitely Manusmriti is not Manu's work.

Comment: Manu is being referred in third person because it is the student of his who is speaking on behalf of Manu, but like other smritis Manu smriti has interpolations some part are not written by Manu himself. @R. Kaushik