# Who was the Manu that Rig Veda referring to?

Tags: rig-veda, agni, manu

Rig Veda [II.10.6](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02010.htm) says

> जञेया भागं सहसानो वरेण तवादूतासो ***मनुवद वदेम*** | अनूनमग्निं जुह्वा
>   वचस्या मधुप्र्चं धनसाजोहवीमि ||
>
> jñeyā bhāghaṃ sahasāno vareṇa tvādūtāso ***manuvad vadema*** |
>   anūnamaghniṃ juhvā vacasyā madhupṛcaṃ dhanasājohavīmi ||
>
> By choice victorious, recognize thy portion: with thee for envoy may
>   **we speak like Manu.** Obtaining wealth, I call on perfect Agni who with an eloquent tongue dispenses sweetness.

A reference to Manu was made in the above Rig Vedic mantra.  It talks about Manu praising AGNI.

---

Rig Veda II.20.7 says

> sa vṛtrahendraḥ kṛṣṇayonīḥ purandaro dāsīrairayad vi | ajanayan ***manave***
>   kṣāmapaśca satrā śaṃsaṃ yajamānasya tūtot ||
>
> Indra the Vṛtra-slayer, Fort-destroyer, scattered the Dāsa hosts who
>   dwelt in darkness. For ***Manu hath he created earth and waters***, and ever
>   helped the prayer of him who worships.

This Mantra says Indra created Earth and waters for Manu.

---

However, it is not clear whether the Manu being referred to in these mantras, was the same Manu, who was eulogised to be [the first man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manu_(Hinduism)) (progenitor of humanity) on the Earth or someone else.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Related: [Mention in Yajurveda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31999/277)

Comment: @Paṇḍyā: Yajur veda may contain such references.  My question is whether he is the same Manu>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rig Veda [III.5.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03005.htm) says

> adhāyyaghnirmānuṣīṣu vikṣvapāṃ gharbho mitra ṛtena sādhan | ā haryato
> yajataḥ sānvasthādabhūdu vipro havyomatīnām ||

Translation of [H.H. Wilson](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_English_Vol_II/#book/230) (p.203) is as follows:

> AGNI. the embryo of the waters. the friend of the pious. accomplishing
> (all desires) with Truth. has been placed (by the gods) ***amongst men.
> the descendants of Manu***: desirable and adorable. he has taken his
> station on high. where the wise AGNI is to receive the oblations of
> the devout.

---

We have to observe the phrase in bold form - ***amongst men.***
***the descendants of Manu***.

So Rig Veda II.10.6, mentioned in the question, was talking only about **Manu**, the first Man.

However, contrary to Puranas, it was **Indra**, who created Earth and waters for Manu.