# How can I change my Varna from Shudra to Brahmin?

Tags: varna

I want to change my Varna from Shudra to Brahmin, what is the procedure as per vedas or other authentic book.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: [How to make Shudra into Brahmin, Kshatriya or Vaishya as per Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/50199/647)

Comment: No one is *born* brahmin. You need threaded initiation for that. Our society during the present time isn't divided into vernas, so that's pretty optional.

Comment: Brother @AbhasKumarSinha I know this, but I was asking for reference from our books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varna is a universal concept and applies to all of humanity. It is a measure of character. Currently Hindus determine Varna by birth and this Varna by birth is called caste in popular usage. A Mahabharata passage from Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII rejects the idea that Varna is by birth.

> Maheshwara said, ‘**..Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor
> learning, nor offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring
> upon one the regenerate status.Verily, the conduct is the only ground.
> All Brahmanas in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of conduct. A
> Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as possessed
> of the status of a Brahmana.** The status of a Brahma, O auspicious
> lady [Uma], is equal wherever it exists. Even this is my opinion. He,
> indeed, is a Brahmana in which the status of Brahma exists – that
> condition which is bereft of attributes and which has no stain
> attached to it. of human beings in four orders dependent on birth is
> only for purposes of classification.**The boon giving Brahma, when he
> created all creatures, himself said that the distribution of human
> beings in four orders dependent on birth is only for purposes of
> classification.'**

**Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII**

Since varna is determined by conduct it is possible to change varna.

**Change of Varna**

> Narada said, 'If in members born in a certain Varna the qualities
> pertaining to another Varna are seen, they (the former) are to be
> classified as belonging to the latter Varna.'

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana VII.11.35**

**Sage Pulastya's views on how to become a Brahmana**

> Sage Pulastya said,"..by vows, by investiture of the sacred, by fasts,
> by rites, and by Mantras, one becometh a Brahmana."

**(Mahabharata, Aranya Parva LXXXIII)**

> Only he who has purified himself by means of Gayatri Japa can be
> called a pure Brahmin. ….

**Shiva Purana, Vidyesvarasamhita, 15.18**

I am supplementing my answer with actual examples of persons who have changed Varna.

**Examples of Change of Varna in Hindu scripture**

> Bhagavan Rishabha, realizing that the region of his advent was a place
> dominated by Vedic rituals, adopted the life of a religious student
> under a teacher with gifts, came back home with his blessings. He
> adopted the householder’s station of life in order to teach the world
> about the duties of that order, observed all the ceremonials and
> duties laid down in the scriptures, married a girl named Jayanti given
> to him by Indra, and begot by her a hundred sons equal to himself in
> all respects. Of all these sons, Bharata was the eldest and noblest.
> This Ajanabha Varsha came to be known after him as Bharatavarsha. Next
> to him, the eldest nine other sons ….. were elder to the remaining
> ninety. Among these ninety, another nine … became great devotees and
> teachers of the Bhakti cult. ….. **The remaining eighty one of the
> brothers, who were humble in nature, learned in the Vedas, adepts in
> sacrificial rites, and extremely pure through their observances,
> became Brahmanas according to their father’s instruction.**

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana, V.4.8-13**

> At Kamyaka, Kusika’s son had quaffed the Soma juice with Indra. Then
> abandoning the Kshatriya order, he began to say,’‘I am a Brahmana’.

**Mahabharata, Vana Parva, Section LXXXVII**

If you have reached here then you need to first check if your claim that you are a shudra is by birth or by conduct. You believe you are a shudra because your parents told you so. Ask your parents if they studied your conduct and then gave you a name appropriate for a Shudra or they believed they are shudras by birth because of their name and hence they named you and told you that you are a shudra. If as I suspect that you think you are a shudra because of birth then you should give up your claim that you are a Shudra. The actual position is that you don't know what is your actual varna.

You want to become a Brahmin. Then you can do some of the things suggested by the Sage Pulastya or do japa of Gayatri obtained from a Guru and become a Brahmin by conduct.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that you have openly asked question. But I never saw anyone asking how to convert from Kshatriya to shudra or from shudra to vaishya or from Brahmana to vaishya etc? Why?

Vedas have revealed that 4 varnas are from God only. As environment, challenges and needs keep on changing in KALI YUGA automatically one may not feel what VARNA he/she must practice. At this context it is better to stick towards one's swadharma to obtain greatest as MOKSHA.

Treating/considering oneself very bad by birth is NOT CORRECT. Earth is a very great place of abundant resources and joy. One must enjoy it.

All four VARNAs must worship GOD through their way to possible extent of their strength.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, being a pure devotee is even above being a Brahmana or being born in a great devotee lineage (and not being a pure devotee).
In the Bhagavata Purana it has been mentioned that one’s actions and personality in their present birth determine their caste. Someone born in a ‘Brahmana family’ who is doing business would be considered to have a Vaishya caste(Part 7, Chapter 11, Verse 35).

The belief that caste is by birth is something the society has created, and personally I believe the British had a great hand in creating this system. Be a pure devotee, and if you want to be a Brahmana do Brahminical duties.

You may face opposition by Brahmanas themselves, and when Shri Krishna came as Caitanya Mahaprabhu 500 years ago he himself said that a lot of Brahmanas are power hungry and foolish (thinking themselves higher than a pure devotee).